# Marionette Layout: $el is not rendered when explicitly defined

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darksoulsong/4HK3D/1/) I have a dummy code of a issue I'm having with $el in a Backbone.Marionette app.

When I define a Layout, even if $el's length is 1, it is not inserted to the page. But everything works if I let the element with its default config, that is, a div.

Here is the code that declares the Application, defines a main region to it, creates a new layout and item views :

```
var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

        App.addRegions({
            page: "#page"
        });

        App.PageLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
            template: "#page-template",
            className: "container",
            regions: {
                header: "#main-header",
                content: "#main-content",
                footer: "#main-footer"
            }
        });

        App.HeaderView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                console.log(this.$el.length); // 1
            },

            el: "#main-header",
            template: "#header-template",
        });

        App.FooterView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                console.log(this.$el.length); // 1
            },
            el: "#main-footer",
            template: "#footer-template"
        });

        App.ContentView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                console.log(this.$el.length); // 1
            },
            el: "#main-content",
            template: "#content-template"
        });



        App.on("initialize:after", function() {
            var pageLayout = new App.PageLayout;

            App.page.show(pageLayout);

            pageLayout.header.show(new App.HeaderView);
            pageLayout.content.show(new App.ContentView);
            pageLayout.footer.show(new App.FooterView);
        });

        App.start();
```

**The templates:**

```
<script id="header-template" type="text/template">
        Awesome Inc.
    </script>
    <script id="footer-template" type="text/template">
        <li> <a href="#">Like us on Facebook</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tweet us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Hate us on Hatey.com</a> </li>
    </script>
    <script id="page-template" type="text/template">
        <header id="main-header"></header>
        <section id="main-content"></section>
        <footer id="main-footer"></footer>
    </script>
    <script id="footer-template" type="text/template">
        <li> <a href="#">Like</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tweet us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Hate</a> </li>
    </script>
    <script id="content-template" type="text/template">
        <h1>Welcome to this World</h1>
    </script>
```

**And finally, the main element, in the page:**

```
<main id="page">Loading...</main>
```

I need the layout to find the region that was rendered (since the App instance has handled that already) and append the related ItemView content to it.

I wonder if I'm missing something really obvious.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT**

After some pointers by @DavidSulc, I have figured out that I'm unable to do this the way I need.

That means I can't create some regions in the layout, attach some item views, making the item views' el the same as the regions defined on the layout. So I will learn to like the extra div created inside the region. In my opinion, this just causes extra and undesired markup - Why can't I use the region's element as long as it is rendered already?
If there is another way to do this, I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the handlers for each view/region. 

Since they are DOM dependant, if you had the region and view sharing the same element, how would it know what to do if you wanted to either replace the View, or remove the region altogether? It would probably complicate the underlying library to track views and regions in a different manner.

I certainly agree it's annoying, but I've learned to craft my divs and styles in a way that makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fork: http://jsfiddle.net/hR4Sx/1

A few pointers:

- you shouldn't define `el` attributes in your views
- your regions need to be present on the page
- the best way to manage layouts is to render their subviews when the layout itself is shown

Shameless plug: [my Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) covers this type of info (and more!), or you can take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction) if you'd rather learn on your own...

Comment: Hey David, thx for the Help. I'm reading your book right now, BTW. It is helping me a lot, IMO. 

I see what you did there, but my issue is that I don't want that div tag to wrap my main-header template, that's why I have defined the el, so it would use the "#main-header" element that was previously rendered by the application "show" method. And the regions where there when the views  rendered (notice the "console.log(this.$el) from the view initializer.

Could you explain more about your comment about "not defining the el in my views"? Why is that a bad practice? 

Thx a lot.

Comment: To clarify, you can specify an `el` in views, but you rarely do because usually you'll create your own to host the view. The problem in your case is that you're trying to use the same DOM element to act as the region container AND the view container simultaneously. This seems like a bad idea to me and will likely lead to conflicts. A view basically MUST be contained in its own DOM node, but you can define which one (instead of `div`) with the `tagName` attribute.

Comment: can you post me a free version of your book, i am very passionate about backbone.js